# Isoperimetric Problems

Tags: differential-geometry

I'd like to apologize for the length beforehand, this has been an issue for me for some time and this is somewhat the last resort to get some external help.

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a domain in ht euclidean plane bounded by a simple closed parametrised curve $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ of which has unit speed $(|\gamma'| =1)$ for any smooth positive function $\psi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ show the relation holds

$$
4\pi \int\int_{\Omega} \psi(x)\psi(y) dydx \leq \int [\psi^2(x(t)) + \psi^2(y(t))] dt
$$
Also it should be known that $\gamma(t) = (x(t),y(t))$

Obviously, the nature of the question is an isoperimetric problem and so we have the isoperimetric inequality
$$
4\pi A \leq L^2
$$
Where $L$ is Length and has equation $\int_{0}^{1} |\gamma'(t)| dt$. My idea is to make $\psi$ a function that acts as "you differentiate this" so to speak, for example if $\gamma(t) = (x(t),y(t))$ then $\psi(\gamma(t)) = \gamma'(t) = (x'(t),y'(t))$ and so far this works for deriving the right hand side of the equation since:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} |\gamma'(t)| dt = \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{(x'(t))^2 + (y'(t))^2} dt = \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{[\psi(x(t))]^2 + [\psi(y(t))]^2} dt\
$$
Now using the interchangabilty of $(\psi(x(t)))^2 = \psi^2(x(t))$, I get that
$$
L = \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{[\psi^2(x(t))] + [\psi^2(y(t))]} dt
$$
So $L^2$ just gets rid of the square root which gives me my right-hand side. Now here's where things I feel get a bit "wishy-washy", If I let $n(t)$ be a unit normal vector to $\gamma$ (implying that it has property $det(\gamma(t),n(t)) = -1$ and so $n(t)=(-y'(t),x'(t))$ then I have the relation (from my lecture notes, my lecturer doesn't mind us using proven things from the lecture notes for our exams due to the pandemic)

$$
2A = -\int_{0}^{1} (\gamma(t)\cdot n(t)) dt 
= \int_{0}^{1} (xy'-yx')(t) dt = \int_{0}^{1} xdy - ydx =
\\ \int\int_{\Omega} \bigg(\frac{\delta x}{\delta x} + \frac{\delta y}{\delta y}\bigg) dxdy 
$$
Where Im trying to use the green's identity to weeve in the double integral however I'm pretty sure that I'm doing this incorrectly?

Thanks In advance, I look forward to any help at all, even if it's to tell me that I have done everything wrong thus far!

Comment: $\psi$ and $\gamma$ are arbitrary, you cannot make $\psi$ "act as if differentiating" $\gamma$. Also, $L^2$ doesn't get rid of the square (the product of integrals is not the integral of the product).

Comment: @andres1 How come I can't just multiply the integral by itself, since the length is the integral of the speed so this is just 1? and $1^2 = 1$, generally I do agree with the general rule of thumb, but yeah if I can't have $\psi$ act like this I guess it's back to the drawing board :(

Comment: This comment is not relevant to what you're doing. $\psi$ has nothing to do with $\gamma$, and you seem to be forgetting that $\psi$ is a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$.